docker: 'compose' is not a docker command Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I tried to run
docker compose up

on a Ubuntu 24.04 LTS system and encountered the error
docker: 'compose' is not a docker command

The current docker --version is 24.0.7 which appears to be a current or very recent version.
Docker migrated away from the old docker-compose Python CLI quite some time ago, so I'm not sure why this isn't working.
Do I possibly need to install another apt package?
A search of apt-cache search docker | grep compose gives the following results.
docker-compose - define and run multi-container Docker applications with YAML
docker-compose-v2 - tool for running multi-container applications on Docker
podman-compose - Run docker-compose.yml using podman
python3-compose - Python implementation of docker-compose file specification


docker-compose-v2 is the required apt package. Install it with
sudo apt install docker-compose-v2

The full list of packages to install is
sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin

see the official documentation

According to the official documentation:

For Ubuntu and Debian, run:

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install docker-compose-plugin



E: Unable to locate package docker-compose-plugin

As per the official documenetation
If you follow the steps you will be able to install compatible docker and docker compose sucessfully which you can run smoothly in ubuntu , if your os is supported by docker.

check if you are using UFW firewall or not in the first there is a setup stating what you need to do in the docs

check the version of Ubuntu and figure out if its compatible with docker.

uninstall old docker installations and setup using following command:
for pkg in docker.io docker-doc docker-compose docker-compose-v2 podman-docker containerd runc; do sudo apt-get remove $pkg; done

you have 4 methods to install docker you can see Installation method section.

I prefer installing with Install using the apt repository where in the first step Set up Docker's apt repository. you will get a script and you just need to copy in your terminal and run it, everything is done for you if you meet the previous steps requirements.


# Add Docker's official GPG key:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates curl
sudo install -m 0755 -d /etc/apt/keyrings
sudo curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.asc
sudo chmod a+r /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.asc

# Add the repository to Apt sources:
echo \
  "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.asc] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
  $(. /etc/os-release && echo "$VERSION_CODENAME") stable" | \
  sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
sudo apt-get update


got to next step Install the Docker packages. here you can install all the latest docker packages with following command which i ususally do :

sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin


you can test your docker is working or not with simple docker command:

sudo docker run hello-world

here you might face issue of need to use sudo command  to docker command you just need to follow this docs how to run docker without sudo in post installation documentation
I am writing a long answer, even docker instalaltion is not in the question because ususally we tend to install docker and docker compose separately without following the steps and run into issue like OP and one of the person answering this question is going thrugh. Its better to follow official document steps one by one as per the requiremnt and make a script so that you just run to setup everything at once and save your time.
